# Python how to make the outside of all contours black?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using mask-RCNN to detect objects in an image then I draw contours on the image using the objects masks like this [contours in an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdX7p.jpg)

Then I want to make every pixel outside those contours to be black something like this: [contours with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j180k.jpg)
so is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html and binary operations (masking) what *exactly* is the issue here? did you just want a tutorial?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz my problem is not with drawing contours. I can successfully do it. Now I want to change each pixel outside all contours in the picture to black colour as in the second image provided in the question.

Comment: your problem _is_ with drawing contours. draw them filled and white. now you have a **mask**. a **mask** is what you want so you can erase stuff that's **not in the mask**. look up "mask/masking operations".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your help it was not exactly what I needed but it put me on the right way to figure it out :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a mask by using `cv2.FILLED` while drawing contours and apply to the original image.
ex:

```py
black_canvas = np.zeros_like(img_gray)
cv2.drawContours(black_canvas, contours, -1, 255, cv2.FILLED) # this gives a binary mask
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the contours, you can obtain your result by first creating a mask image of the contours and then performing a bitwise_and operation using that mask.

```py
maskImage = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(maskImage, Contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

newImage = cv2.bitwise_and(img, maskImage)
```