# python dealing with coordinates for image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have one question about image contour processing.

Like this, I have the polygon coordinates of interested area.

`[array([[ 877, 1050]], dtype=int32), array([[ 876, 1051]], dtype=int32), ..., array([[1070, 1172]], dtype=int32)]`

Using these coordinates, I want to whiten the outside of the contour.
[image]

Is there a way to do this process in Python?
It would be nice to be able to use opencv.

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. Firstly, you have joined your input image to your output image - making it harder to process just the input image. Secondly, it is not clear if your image is really representative of your actual image - is the stuff inside your blue area actually a solid colour or does it contain more detail than that? If solid, the processing is potentially simpler. Also, you show no attempt at code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to make the outside of all contours black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718592/python-how-to-make-the-outside-of-all-contours-black)